# How to get rid of superfluous slashes in url in django

Tags: django, url

I have an issue with extra slashes in the url in django. I have url subdomain.domain.com/, but subdomain.domain.com//// shows the same page. I need that people, who entering subdomain.domain.com////, are redirected to subdomain.domain.com/ or receive 404. This is the way how I define the url in urls.py: 
`urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),]`

Comment: "are redirected to subdomain.domain.com/ or receive 404."

What do you want? It's either one or the other.

Comment: Preferably 1 option, but if you explain how to do both, I'll be happy

Comment: I cannot recreate your problem in Django 2.0. I used `path` instead of `url` to define my URLs. Can you give a little more detail? Maybe check the RegEx you have used to include the root url of the app in the project url. See if there's a wildcard like `*` somewhere at the end of the url.

Comment: Currently I am using Django 1.9. The app's urls file includes like this url(r'^', include('website.urls', namespace='website')),